# Cordova ios Page Shrinking

Tags: ios, cordova, screen, shrink

[image: shrink screen]

[image: original screen]

I have page shrinking problem in cordova iOS platform. When clicking the input text field, it opens the keyboard.

I am facing the screen shrinking problem when clicking outside the already focused text field and didn't close the keyboard which is already opened. If I close or exit the opened keyboard, then there is no problem. The screen shrink is not coming.

With this I attached my screenshot. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: same thing happening, did u find a solution ?

Comment: so the keyboard closes and the page is still at the shrink state..?